# Better way to dismiss subwindow than series of casts?

Tags: java, swing, window, dismiss

I have a subwindow that performs a search on a DB. On clicking the "Select" button on the subwindow, I want to return the results of the search to the calling window AND dismiss the subwindow. My code is doing this fine, BUT, I was just wondering if there was a better way to dismiss the subwindow than this:

```
((JDialog)((JPanel)(JButton)evt.getSource()).getParent()).getTopLevelAncestor()).dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

The intermediate step of getting the `JPanel` parent is not necessary since `JComponent` defines `getTopLevelAncestor()`:

```
((JDialog)((JButton)event.getSource()).getTopLevelAncestor()).dispose();
```

For better readability you can also write:

```
SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((JButton)event.getSource()).dispose();
```

Comment: Works for me. Thank you!